# Responsibility of implementing hashcode and equal

Tags: java

I have an interface called Work

```
public class interface Work {
    boolean completeWork(Job j);
}
```

Then I have a Composite class

```
public class CompositeWork implements Work {
    private Set<Work> childWork = new HashSet<>();
    public boolean completeWork(Job j) {
        return childWork.stream().allMatch(w -> w.completeWork(j));
    }
    public void addWork(Work w) {
        childWork.add(w);
    }
}
```

I have a different Work types are the follwoing:

```
public class EasyWork implements Work {
    public boolean completeWork(Job j) {
        <do some work>
    }
} 

public class HardWork implements Work {
    private String id;
    public Hardwork(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public boolean completeWork(Job j) {
        <do some work>
    }
}
```

Client populate CompositeWork something like this

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompositeWork workHolder = new CompositeWork();
        workHolder.add(new EasyWork());
        workHolder.add(new EasyWork());
        workHolder.add(new HardWork("1"));
        workHolder.add(new HardWork("2"));
    }
}
```

To enforce uniqueness of `childWork` in `CompositeWork` in `HashSet<>()` where do i implement `hashcode()` and `equals()`?

Does that occur in Work interface?
CompositeWork class?
or is it implemented inside EasyWork and HardWork?

Comment: In `EasyWork` and `HardWork`.

Comment: And also `CompositeWork`, because that could also be added to the hash set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can't answer the question for you.** It depends on how you want the classes to behave.

The default behavior for any class is that different instances will compare unequal to each other. If you are okay with all `EasyWork` objects being distinct and all `HardWork` objects being distinct, even when they contain the same data, then you don't need to do anything. **The default methods may suffice.**

Otherwise, you should examine each class on a **case-by-case basis**:

- If you want `HardWork` objects to be equal if they have the same `id`, on the other hand, then you need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `HardWork`. If not, don't bother.
- Similarly, if `EasyWork` objects should be equal to each other then you'll need to override them there as well. If not, don't bother.
- Furthermore, if you want `CompositeWork` objects to be equal to each other if they have the same `Set` of children then you should override them there, too. If not, don't bother.

Comment: this may be an orthogonal question but is that mean equals uses hashcode to determine whether something is the same? then wouldnt just changing hashcode alone suffice?

Comment: [If you override one, then you should override the other.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to distinguish between `EasyWork` & `HardWork`, you need to implement those methods in those classes.

Here is a good [article](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java) about this topic.

Comment: not only i want to distinguish bewteen EasyWork and HardWork, I may want to distinguish amongst themselves. from EasyWork(A) to EasyWork(B)

Answer (score 1):

I see the answer of [John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman) and I almost agree. Almost - because there is one pretty important thing that is being often forgotten. If you are going to use `EasyWork` and `HardWork` objects in a hash-dependant collection like `HashSet`, besides overriding `equals` and `hashcode` you have to make your classes immutable. It means, that

1. both of your classes have to be `final`
2. fields, that are going to used by your `equals` and `hashcode` methods, have to be final.

**Explanation**

If the object is not immutable, then you can change some of its fields, then its `hashCode` will return a new result, and then you will be unable to access this object in collection due to a wrong location in hashtable.